# Getting AutoScaling group in Cloudformation

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I'm working with `Cloudformation` and 
I'm configuring `autoscaling` group in `AWS::ElasticBeanstalk::ConfigurationTemplate` using `aws:autoscaling:asg`.
Now I need to get AutoScaling group name to implement `AWS::AutoScaling::LifecycleHook`. Is there any way to get `AutoScaling` group name. Please help me to resolve this.

Answer (score 0):

CloudFormation now has a property called: AutoScalingGroupName

```
Type: "AWS::AutoScaling::AutoScalingGroup"
Properties:
  AutoScalingGroupName: String
  AvailabilityZones:
    - String
  Cooldown: String
  DesiredCapacity: String
  HealthCheckGracePeriod: Integer
  HealthCheckType: String
  InstanceId: String
  LaunchConfigurationName: String
  LaunchTemplate" : LaunchTemplateSpecification
  LifecycleHookSpecificationList: 
    - LifecycleHookSpecification
  LoadBalancerNames:
    - String
  MaxSize: String
  MetricsCollection:
    - MetricsCollection
  MinSize: String
  NotificationConfigurations:
    - NotificationConfiguration
  PlacementGroup: String
  ServiceLinkedRoleARN: String
  Tags:
    - TagProperty
  TargetGroupARNs:
    - String
  TerminationPolicies:
    - String
  VPCZoneIdentifier:
    - String
```

[image]

Reference:- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-as-group.html

Comment: Hi Karan, Can I add Autoscaling group name to OptionSettings in AWS::ElasticBeanstalk::ConfigurationTemplate.

Comment: yes, you can. Just have a look for the reference

https://github.com/bimlendu/Cloudformation/blob/master/AutoScalingGroup.template.json